# OrderBy ThenBy in F#

Tags: .net, linq, sorting, f#

Is there any function in F# similar to LINQ fluent syntax for sorting by multiple expressions:

```
myList.OrderBy(fun x->x.Something).ThenBy(fun x->x.SomethingElse)
```

I'd love something like:

```
myList 
|> Seq.sort_by(fun x->x.Something) 
|> Seq.then_by(fun x->x.SomethingElse)
```

Thx

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Use a tuple as your sort key:

```
myList |> Seq.sortBy (fun x -> x.Something, x.SomethingElse)
```

Comment: Right, tuples sort in lexicographical order, so putting multiple keys in order left-to-right in a tuple does just what is desired.

Comment: @tim-robinson do you know how one would do this type of sort with alphanum/natural sort for each item in the key?

Comment: @Erick I'd implement IComparable by hand, and either call Seq.sortBy (wrapping the sort key in my custom IComparable implementation), or call System.Linq.Enumerable.OrderBy (and pass my IComparable as a parameter).

Comment: This is exactly the kind of elegant solution I've come to expect from the F# standard library

Answer (score 13):

Because `sortBy` is [defined to be stable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.sortby%5B%27t%2c%27key%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D#remarks), you can sort multiple times, using the secondary key(s) in reverse order:

```ml
myList |> Seq.sortBy (fun x -> x.SomethingElse) |> Seq.SortBy (fun x -> x.Something)
```

Items that compare the same for the primary key will retain the previous ordering done by the secondary key. Items that compare the same for **both** keys will be in the original order. This has the advantage (unlike the tuple method) that you can control whether the sort is descending for each of the keys independently.

If your sort keys are signed integers and you wish to sort, say, the secondary key in descending order, you can still use the tuple method using negation:

```ml
myList |> Seq.sortBy (fun x -> x.Something, -x.SomethingElse)
```

This method is arguably less clear, but may be faster than sorting twice. Be aware that it does not correctly handle the smallest value correctly because of overflow.

Comment: Hi Rick, thank you for teaching me about stable sorts. Could you clarify what you mean by "Be aware that it does not correctly handle the smallest value correctly because of overflow."?

Comment: Ah, I understand now. E.g. signed byte goes from -128 to 127, so you can't negate the -128.